# Getting reference to pdfjsLib using the @types/pdfjs-dist in Angular

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, angular-material, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I am trying to use the pdf.js library in a pre-compiled Angular 9 project.

I install using `npm i --save pdfjs-dist` and `npm i --save @types/pdfjs-dist`

Then from what I see online, I should be able to use `import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist';` to access it within my component. The problem is I get this error in my compiler:

[image: error message]

I have tried many other ways to get a reference, but they either can't get the reference, or throw the same error message.

I have also tried what is suggested here: [Importing namespace and interface with methods in TypeScript (TSX) in pdfjs-dist (PDFJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47755268/importing-namespace-and-interface-with-methods-in-typescript-tsx-in-pdfjs-dist)
however, I get errors telling me that PDFJSStatic is not an exported member.

[image: error 2]

Any help at all would be appreciated!

My goal is to be able to use the getDocument() function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it's the most updated version at moment.

> npm i @libusoftcicom/pdfjs-dist

```
import * as pdfjsLib from '@libusoftcicom/pdfjs-dist';
import { PDFPageProxy, PDFJSStatic } from '@libusoftcicom/pdfjs-dist/types/display/api';
```

Put this one somewhere in your load function.

```
const pdfjsWorker = await import('@libusoftcicom/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry');
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker;
```